# What is the fundamental difference between these two neural network structures?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

What is the underlying difference in the processing of a neural network that receives, for example, three separate inputs to give a single output and a network that takes a single input of size `3` to give one output?

If at all there is any difference, then when and where would one be more applicable or useful than the other? Also, what is the best way of assigning inputs to the first network (the one with several inputs)?

Answer (score 0):

Neural networks receive one or more **instances**, or **feature vectors**, as input, which they either learn from or make predictions on.

One such instance is usually a **vector**. Each element of the vector gets assigned to an **input neuron**, which simply returns what its assigned to the (first) hidden layer neurons.

So there is no difference between "three separate inputs" and "a single input of size `3`", as far as I know and understand your question. In my opinion, it's more correct to say "a single input of size `3`", because you input one instance at a time, and that instance has a certain size (of course, optimized implementations allow you to input more at a time by using matrix multiplications, but conceptually, neural networks handle a single instance a time).

> Also, what is the best way of assigning inputs to the first network (the one with several inputs)?

Like I said, the elements of each instance or feature vector are assigned to an input neuron, that simply returns its input. This is the **input layer**.